# Incrementing(+) text size via delayed loop on 'mouseover'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a `<p>` that first renders nearly invisible, then on 'mouseover' becomes visible and incrementally increases in size, to finally 1em.  Then on 'mouseout' reverts to its original settings.  For the delay, I'm using a sleep() function referenced from [this(stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript) answer(works great, thank you).

What's happening is that while the increment works fine, the `<p>` doesn't appear until the end of the loop.  Suddenly, rather than throughout, and I'm not sure why...  The 'mouseout' event works fine.  Tested in firefox, chrome and safari on OS X 10.9 same in all three.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime(), i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

var Test_MouseOver = function (event) {
    var i, text_size;

    $('#Test').css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.6)').css('color', 'rgba(100, 0, 0, 1)');

    for (i = 0.2; i <= 1; i = i + 0.1) {
        text_size = i.toString() + 'em';

        console.info('i: ' + text_size);

        $('#Test').css('font-size', text_size);

        sleep(50);
    }

    console.info('-----');
};

var Test_MouseOut = function (event) {
    $('#Test').css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)').css('color', 'rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.2)').css('font-size', '0.2em');
};

var Test = document.getElementById('Test');

Test.addEventListener('mouseover', Test_MouseOver);
Test.addEventListener('mouseout', Test_MouseOut);
```

Comment: Well, apparently the `sleep` **does not work great**. Never use such a thing, but [do it properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14327647/1048572)

Comment: Are you sure it's the sleep() that is causing the issue? The DOM and console register the incrementing font-size just fine.  How would the sleep function be interfering with the rendering?  The entirety of the loop lasts for less than a second, so it doesn't really cause any browser lag.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, would you be open to using jQuery's `animate`? Or, is this for learning??

Comment: Learning.  `animate` you say...I'm going to look into that immediately.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's the `sleep`. Busy waiting *does* block rendering. In some browsers, the console is affected by this as well.

Comment: Ohhh, I see.  So, solutions seem to be pure CSS, `animate`, `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`.  Testing all of them, I'll post which work best for my intended result.  Thanks for all the answers everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

```
setInterval(function() {
  // do stuff every 50ms
}, 50);
```

Comment: HMM, I'm going to test this right now, hadn't encountered that function yet.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem. You also might be come to need `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

pure **CSS3**:

```css
#Test{
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  color: rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size:0.2em;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out 3s; /* 3s is the mouseleave delay */
}
#Test:hover{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.6);
  color: rgba(100, 0, 0, 1);
  font-size: 1em;
  transition-delay: 0s; /* 0s delay on mouseenter */
}
```

```html
 <div id="Test">Hello world</div>
```

---

P.S:

instead of nesting `.css().css()` use object notation:

```
.css({
      background : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)",
      color      : "rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.2)",
      font-size  : "0.2em"
})
```

Comment: lol  Yeah, I know I can do it with CSS, but JS is fun!  Plus I want it to scale up over the delay rather than POP up.  (edit) Oh, transition animates the transition?

Comment: @NathanHine `POPup?`... c'mon have you tried to modify `2s` transition time to i.e: `6s`? (CSS3 vs JS in animations?... I would not say so )

Comment: **VERY** interesting.  I'm going to play around with this thoroughly.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm still learning atm, CSS3 transitions fall late into the Advanced category.  Thank you for pointing me to them.  JS is still fun though.  :)

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]I've arrived at a solution using `.animate()` and `setTimeout()`  that achieves my desired result.  The `<p>` appears on 'mouseover' scales up to 1em then disappears 5 seconds later.  I removed the 'mouseout' event as obsolete.  Thank you for the feedback everyone, I now have several new tools in my JS and CSS3 belts.

```
var Restore_Settings = function (event) {
    $('#test').css({
        background  :   'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)',
        color       :   'rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.2)',
        'font-size' :   '0.2em'
    });
};

var Test_MouseOver = function (event) {
    var DelayInterval, RestoreInterval;
    DelayInterval = 2000;
    RestoreInterval = 5000;

    $('#test').css({
        color       :   'rgba(100, 0, 0, 1)'
    });

    $('#test').animate({ 
        'font-size' :   '1em' },
        DelayInterval
    );

    setTimeout(Restore_Settings, RestoreInterval);
};
```

As this is my first question, I'm not sure if it's bad practice to post a [Solved] answer to my own question.  Let me know if so, please.  Thanks.